# Searching with date only

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a Rails 4.1.4 web app and I want to search by a specific date.
When I search for "2014-07-01" I find nothing but when I search for "2014-07-01 10:00:00" I do find because that is the exact date (with time) in the database.

This is my code:

@timereports = Timereport.where("reported_at = ?", Time.parse(params[:date]))

How can I match only the date and ignore the time part?

Answer (score 1):

Dates are tricky, you have to compare the right type. In one you're using a `date` and the other a `datetime`. If you only care to find records at a certain date and not a specific time you'll need to cast the db field to a date:

```
@timereports = Timereport.where("DATE(reported_at) = ?", Date.parse(params[:date]))
```

That says to convert the db field `reported_at` to a `DATE` (e.g. "2014-07-01") and to compare it to `Date.parse(params[:date])` which is also now "2014-07-01".